# AWS CLI 2のレスポンスが遅い

Tags: aws, aws-cli

windows10でaws cli ver2を公式通りにインストールし、git bashで
`aws --version`を実行しましたが、バージョンの表示まで何十秒もかかる状態です。
power shellなどでも同様の状態でした。

原因がわからないのですが、どなたかご存じでしょうか

Answer (score 1):

`aws --version`を何回か実行するとだんだん早くなりませんか？

こちらで試してみたところ、`aws --version`が完了するまでに`CreateFile`（いわゆるファイルオープン）が2000回近く実行されており、大量のファイルアクセスを必要とするようです。何回か実行するとそれらのファイルはキャッシュに乗るため、次第に改善する傾向が見られました。

Answer (score 0):

直接の回答ではありませんが、WSLでawsをインストールしたところ、現象は再現しませんでした。数秒で帰ってきます。

```
【インストール手順】
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user
sudo apt install awscli
```

Win10でしたらWSLを有効化し、WSLでawsをインストールしてはいかがでしょうか。

WSLであればstraceでシステムコールレベルの実行時刻が確認できますので、どこで時間がかかっているのかが分かるかもしれません。

```
strace -tt aws --version
```